Rockwell TSO operating system?
I just came across a spec sheet for the little-known Rockwell PPS-8. It states that development is possible on Tymshare, Genie, or "Rockwell TSO". Googling the latter turns up nothing, and I suspect this is actually IBM TSO with modifications? Anyone know for sure?

Link to the spec sheet, for those interested. "Rockwell TSO Operating System", p 2-3. Could also be something internal to Rockwell...

And the PPS-4 datasheet does mention "IBM TSO timesharing systems" on page 7, instead of "Rockwell TSO", after GE and Tymshare.

“Rockwell TSO operating system” what? That’s not a complete sentence.

I see some promising stuff on Tymshare tapes: https://github.com/search?q=org%3ATYMCOM-X+rockwell+pps&type=code

Partial answer:
This PPS-4 data sheet says on page 26 after a list of development software (assembler, emulator, ...):

NOTE: The above support software is available for use via the following computer timesharing systems:

General Electric Information Service Mark III System
Tymshare Incorporated TYMCOM-X system

The Fortran source decks for the above systems and for the IBM 360 TSO system are available for purchase. The Fortran source deck of the assembler program for several popular minicomputers is also available

The PPS-8 was released at the same time as the PPS-4/1, so it's highly likely that the supporting software ran on the same systems.
So "Rockwell TSO" could either mean "IBM TSO with modifications" or "a specific IBM TSO system run at Rockwell, accessible for customers" since you had to buy the source for IBM TSO in general.

From the datasheet: XXX on Tymshare, GE Information Services, and Rockwell TSO Operating System In the day, development tools were often placed on timesharing systems/services. Tymshare was a commercial timesharing service. Clients could login via dialup modems.  Similar for GE IS. There were few custom timesharing OSes for IBM mainframes: McGill Univ Rax (co-developed by Boston Univ) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Remote_Access_Computing, National CSS's VP/CSS, and IBM's TSO. So, most likely, "Rockwell TSO" was a similar service vs. a custom TSO version.
